# Open Specific Settings as Launcher intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

How to open Airplane mode settings, Location Settings and data roaming settings as Launcher
I have tried following code for open data roaming settings, but it is not working

```
final  Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final ComponentName cn = new  ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

How to find out context and activity name of these activites

Comment: What happens if you simply do `startActivity (new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS));`? Keep in mind though, that you are choosing an Activity that may not work on devices without a radio.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Two problems while doing like this. 1. closing settings app destroys my application also. 2, Once i minimize settings by pressing home button and opening my app again brings the settings window first